# Cannot find module "child_process"

Tags: typescript, ionic3, sinch, android-sinch-api, sinch-verification

I am trying to use **sinch** in **ionic 3** project for phone verification, and I follow all the step, but I am facing the following error. Did anyone use **sinch**.
I search about it, but could not find any solution.

[image]

My code is

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { userRegistration } from '../../../helper/userRegistration';
import { SigninEnterResponseCodePage } from '../../pages';

declare var require: any;
var SinchClient = require('sinch-rtc');

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-signup-phone-verification',
  templateUrl: 'signup-phone-verification.html',
})
export class SignupPhoneVerificationPage {
  model: userRegistration;
  userData;
  sinchClient: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.sinchClient = new SinchClient({
      applicationKey: 'myKey'
    });
    if (this.navParams.get('userRegistrationData')) {
      this.userData = this.navParams.get('userRegistrationData');
      this.model = new userRegistration(this.userData.gender, this.userData.dateOfBirth);
    }
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log("model is ", this.model);
    console.log("sinch information  ", SinchClient);

    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SignupPhoneVerificationPage');
  }
  gotoToSigninPhoneVerification() {
    var verification = this.sinchClient.createSmsVerification(myPhone);
    verification.initiate(
      (data) => {
        console.log("resposne data from sinch server is ", data);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log("error received from sinch is ", error);
      });
  }

}
```

Comment: Please please please avoid using images to show textual information! Add them as quote or code block, not as screenshot. This allows searching for the content, easier quoting and so on.